# Agilizar funcion para formato de fecha

Tags: javascript

Hace poco me han metido en un proyecto para intentar optimizar una aplicación. En un punto concreto se pinta una tabla que ronda las 20000 líneas mediante javascript.

El caso es que en una columna pintan una fecha para que se vea en la zona horaria del cliente y usan la función que podes ver aquí:

```js
var dateFormatFunction = function(stringDate){
        var date = new Date(stringDate);
        var limitDate = new Date("1970-01-01");
        if (date > limitDate)
            return date.toLocaleDateString(navigator.language,{ day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }) + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString();
        else
            return "";
};

console.log("Inicio para una sola peticion: " + new Date());
dateFormatFunction("2021-07-01T12:31:41.612Z");
console.log("Fin para una sola peticion: " + new Date());

console.log("Inicio para 20000 peticion: " + new Date());
for (var i = 1; i <= 20000; i++) {
dateFormatFunction("2021-07-01T12:31:41.612Z");
}
console.log("Fin para 20000 peticion: " + new Date());
```

Si ejecutáis el código, para una línea es un tiempo despreciable, pero para las 20000 líneas el renderizado de la tabla se incrementa en 4 segundos (aun mas en la aplicación ya que usa mas funciones para renderizar).

He propuesto usar moment pero se niegan, porque el framework que se usa es propio y no quieren meter ningún plugin extra a excepción de jquery.

El caso es que no me queda mas remedio que optimizar esa función para que sea mas rápida, pero no se como hacerlo, ya que solo es una línea de código.

¿A alguno se le ocurre como hacerlo? Ya he optimizado algunas otras, cambiando if por switch que son mas rapidos, pero esta me esta volviendo loco.

Espero alguno se le ocurra algo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se podría tratar de optimizar esa función, pero el problema, a mi juicio es otro. Se debería de evitar pedir a la DB (entiendo que los datos para pintar la tabla se obtienen de una petición a la DB) y posteriormente renderizar esos volúmenes de datos. Para ello lo suyo sería hacer paginación en esa consulta, para ir obteniendo los resultados de 100 en 100 (por ejemplo). De esta manera, el costo de tiempo de la función que nos muestras sería asumible.

Comment: El código debes escribirlo en la pregunta y no como enlace externo. Saludos

Comment: Estoy trantando de encontrarle el sentido lo que hace la función dateFormatFunction. ¿Por que no siempre hay que dar formato? ¿Por que das formato a la fecha por separado de la hora? Considera que esto puede dar resultados incorrectos.

Comment: _moment.js_ recomienda no usar su propia librería para nuevos proyectos, te invito a leer [Moment.js Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: La funcion esa estaba asi, yo no la hice. No siempre da formato porque si llega 01/01/0001 no hay que pintarla, entiendo que por eso pusieron el if... y lo de dar formato por separado a fecha y hora, es porque debe verse con el desfase horario del cliente y creo que "toLocaleDateString" no pinta la hora, solo la fecha